# BLE Indicate UWP GATT Client

Tags: notifications, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, myo

I was wondering, if there is a problem with the UWP Bluetooth API and Indicate.
If I understand the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/gatt-client#subscribing-for-notifications) correctly UWP will handle the Acknowledgment of a received Indicate package. 
But for some reason, the sample code works for notifys but not for indicates. I am trying this with a Myo Wristband.
I can receive notifications via notify characteristics but not via the indicates one. Unfortunately I have to use indicate.

I changed the sample code a little bit to this, but its not working:

```
GattCommunicationStatus status = await selectedCharacteristic.WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync(
    GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue.Indicate);

if(status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
{
    // Server has been informed of clients interest.
}
```

and the Handler stays the same:

```
characteristic.ValueChanged += Characteristic_ValueChanged;
// ... 
void Characteristic_ValueChanged(GattCharacteristic sender, 
                                    GattValueChangedEventArgs args)
{
    // An Indicate or Notify reported that the value has changed.
    var reader = DataReader.FromBuffer(args.CharacteristicValue)
    // Parse the data however required.
}
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? The device is connected and correctly programed, it sends the notifications.

Thanks in Advance for any help

Marcel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. It was not a problem of UWP, but of the Myo. The code above works for Indicate, just change the notify to indicate and your good to go.

For everyone else in the future. I was making a mistake with the command bytes. 
I misunderstood the Bluetooth Header file and thought that the payload equals the command, but it not like that. So after each command byte you have to send the amount bytes, you give as "argument". This is the payload. Its said in the header, but I somehow missed it.

So for example, to set the myo to EMG_none, IMU_send_all, Classifier_Enabled you have to send this byte to the CommandCharacteristic:

```
01 03 00 03 01
```

where the first 01 is the set_mode,
the first 03 the payload (3 "Arguments"),
the 00 the EMG_none,
the second 03 the IMU_send_all,
the last 01 the Classifier_enabled.

Wished they had made an example command on their tutorial :-)

The full header can be found here: https://github.com/thalmiclabs/myo-bluetooth/blob/master/myohw.h

and a short explanation here: http://developerblog.myo.com/myo-bluetooth-spec-released/

Hope that will help someone.

Comment: Yeah forgot that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not all characteristic are Indicate.

I do not have a MYO, but did some research and found a  list with the characteristics of the MYO:

ControlService     0x0001        Myo info service

MyoInfoCharacteristic          0x0101    Serial number for this Myo and various parameters which  are specific to this firmware. Read-only attribute.

FirmwareVersionCharacteristic  0x0201    Current firmware version. Read-only characteristic.

CommandCharacteristic          0x0401    Issue commands to the Myo. Write-only characteristic.

ImuDataService                 0x0002    IMU service

IMUDataCharacteristic          0x0402    Notify-only characteristic.

MotionEventCharacteristic      0x0502    Motion event data. Indicate-only characteristic.

ClassifierService              0x0003    Classifier event service.

ClassifierEventCharacteristic  0x0103    Classifier event data. Indicate-only characteristic.

EmgDataService                 0x0005    Raw EMG data service.

EmgData0Characteristic         0x0105    Raw EMG data. Notify-only characteristic.

EmgData1Characteristic         0x0205    Raw EMG data. Notify-only characteristic.

EmgData2Characteristic         0x0305    Raw EMG data. Notify-only characteristic.

EmgData3Characteristic         0x0405    Raw EMG data. Notify-only characteristic.

BatteryService                 0x180f    Battery service

BatteryLevelCharacteristic     0x2a19    Current battery level information. Read/notify characteristic.

DeviceName                     0x2a00    Device name data. Read/write characteristic.

Also it is better to use Ibuffer instead of the DataReader. I think the data send by the MYO is BigEndian. With Ibuffer is is easier to change encoding.
Here is an axample how to use Ibuffer:

```
    private async void Characteristic_ValueChanged(GattCharacteristic sender,GattValueChangedEventArgs args)
      {         
         var newValue = FormatValue(args.CharacteristicValue);
         await Task.Run(() => Process_received(newValue));
  }

 private string FormatValue(IBuffer buffer)//using Windows.Storage.Streams;
      {
          CryptographicBuffer.CopyToByteArray(buffer, out byte[] data);//using Windows.Security.Cryptography;
         try
         {
           // return Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes(data) gives char array
           // return Encoding.UTF32.GetString(data)
            return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
         }
         catch (ArgumentException)
         {
            return "Unknown format";
         }
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know the Bluetooth Header List. I can read every Notfiy Characterisitc (e.g. the EMG Characteristic). But I need to get the data from the ClassifierEventCharacteristic and this an Indicate. The problem is not the decoding, my handler is not even triggered. But thanks for the tip with the IBuffer, will change that in the rest of my code :-)

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you need a different event handlers for each characteristic.
Have you tried with only indicate? In all the samples that I could find the Characteristic_ValueChanged is first removed and re-added after change to notify or indicate, which makes no cense if you want to listen to both.